# what should be inside the method getSystemService(context.audio_service) in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to run a program to set the phone to normal mode from silent mode but i dont know what should be inside the method getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)

i have this line of code:

final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

but i think i need to declare or create a method getSystemService and i dont know what should be its content

thank you

Comment: Where in your app are you executing this code?  In an `Activity`?

Comment: i got it now thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to implement`getSystemService()`, it is a method from the [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) class.

`this` should refer to a `Context` instance. In this case, the code you copied likely came from an `Activity` class, which indirectly extends `Context`.

Comment: itslike
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
  Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
  SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
  if (messages.getMessageBody().contains("ALERT ME")) {
   
   //SilentToNomal and NormalToSilent device Programatically
    final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  
   //Normal Mode Programatically
     mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
  }
 }
}